# PHP fopen with c/c+ mode

Tags: php, fread

As far as I am understanding c/c+ mode, I am expecting behaviour like 'a/a+ mode, so the file shouldn't be truncated, and any fwrite() result should be prepended to existing file.

In fact the file seems to be truncated anyway as the file always contains only tle last fwrite() content anyway.

Is it a possible bug in my PHP version (7.0), or I am misunderstanding something?

```
<?php
$fp = fopen($fpath,'c+');
fwrite($fp, date("H:i:s")." test\n");
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: It will not truncate the file on opening. But what makes you think it will prepend to the file? Even though it is not specified (as far as I can see), `fwrite` will likely overwrite data. One person has commented this in the [documentation for fwrite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#90906).

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but if you just want to append content, you could use `file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND);` instead. Shorter and easier.

Comment: @fredrik Thank you, that explains everything!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson This is definitely the best solution at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: It can with the flag `LOCK_EX`. So just use both `FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes you think that this should behave different? According to the documentation, using `c` the pointer is "positioned on the **beginning** of the file". Starting to write from that specific position, you would always override whatever is already present in that file

Comment: Thank you very much. I was focused on 'mode', completely ignoring how fwrite() behaves.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a small addition to what has been said:

```
<?php 
/* file test.txt contains string(4): 'test' */
$fp = fopen('test.txt','c+');
fclose($fp);
```

file `test.txt` is NOT truncated to zero length(as `w` or `w+` would do on `fopen()` ),
it still contains string(4): `test`

Now see what happens when we write one character to the file using `c+`

```
$fp = fopen('test.txt','c+');
fwrite($fp, 'b');
fclose($fp);
```

file `test.txt` now contains: `best`, the file pointer was positioned at the beginning of the file and only overwrites the first character in the original - `test` has become `best`